# display fullscreen img from rss jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, rss

I'm searching an example on how to display the `img` element fullscreen when click on it.
Has anybody an idea?

Here's is a sample of the `rss` feed i `parse`.

```
<channel>
<description><![CDATA[<ul>
  <li>
    Some text
  </li>
  some more text
</ul>
<div align="center">
  <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Xo73N23PJUw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <img src="http://www.123.gr/diafora/2014/sakis-03-06-14.jpg" border="0"></a>
</div>
</description>
</channel>
```

And my code

```
             <?php 
                $html = "";
                $url = "http://123.gr/index.php?format=feed&type=rss";
                $xml = file_get_contents($url);
                $x = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);



foreach ( $x->channel->item as $entry ){
                 ?>
                        }
                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b">
                        <h4><?php echo $entry->title; ?></h4>
                        <p><?php  echo $entry->description; ?></p>
                    </div>
<?php { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. If you get extra pixels just try reseting margin and padding too.

```
.fullSize {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: fullSize is a class.<p class="fullSize">you mean something like that?I don't think this is what i'm looking for.

Comment: At the fiddle you sent I just modified the fullSize class

Comment: Have a look at the answer i post. The fiddle is just an example of how i want the 'img' element of the rss look like

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to create something like that.But idon't know if it is possible.

```
$entry->description = str_replace( '<img/i' , '<img id="imgtab" ', $entry->description);
```

The script code

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#imgtab").toggle(function () { //fired the first time
            $("#imgtab").animate({
                width: "1200px",
                height: "1116px"
            });
            }, function () { // fired the second time 
            $("#imgtab").animate({
                width:  "100%",
                height: "100%"
            });
            });
            });
        </script>
```